# How can I save a variable from a script and access it from another?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, client-server

I have a script that prints out a variable that I want to use in a different javascript file.  I thought that if I save a value as var in a local block that it becomes useable outside of that block.  The var capture prints undefined outside of the function call.

Is it possible to use the value ipcRenderer is giving me in another file?  I have tried making a const and exporting it, but it seems to throw errors when I include it in different .js files that can't have require('electron') because they're client side and not server side.

Because ipcRenderer is printing out a value to console.log on the client side -  is it possible for me to trace where this is being printed and copy the value in order to use in a different value?

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
var capture;
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'received'));

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log("arg: " + arg);
    var testing = arg;   // I want to use this value in a different .js file
    console.log("test: " + testing);
    capture = arg;
});

console.log(capture); // prints undefined.
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'received');
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign the value to `window.testing = arg` ?

Comment: if I change var testing to window.testing and console.log(window.testing) outside of the function it still prints out undefined.

Comment: you could use localStorage for this, store the value there and return it some other point in time.

Comment: So something like localStorage.setItem('myString', 'myStringValue');   ?